# Get time interval with table defined readings

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I am having Below mentioned table and i want to display a report where user can select any time interval as in below table the time interval is of 5 minutes but he want to see every one hour reading then reading at 9:00-->10:00-->... so on should display but there are chances some reading may have skipped
So want to display like that

```
 Date Time               Temperature         Remark      
 26/8/2016 09:05:00          2.3            Power Fail       
 26/8/2016 09:10:00          2.6            out of limit     
 26/8/2016 09:15:00          2.8            out of limit     
 26/8/2016 09:20:00          2.6            out of limit     
 26/8/2016 09:25:00          2.9            Power Fail       
 26/8/2016 09:30:00          3.1            Power Fail       
 26/8/2016 09:35:00          4.1            Power Fail       
 26/8/2016 09:40:00          5.4            out of limit     
 |
 |     
 |
 26/8/2016 23:50:00          6.7            out of limit     
 26/8/2016 13:55:00          5.3            out of limit
```

To excute the same i Tried below mentioned code where textbox one contents time interval which is numeric

```
  Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From ref_1  where DATE_TIME between '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' and '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "' ORDER BY DATE_TIME ASC", conn)
    Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table_1 WHERE DATE_TIME    between '" & DTP1.Value & "' and '" & DTP2.Value & "' ORDER BY DATE_TIME ASC", CON)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "Result")
    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = ds.Tables("Result")
    Dim dcol As New DataColumn()
    dcol.Caption = "DT"
    dcol.ColumnName = "DT"
    dcol.DataType = System.Type.[GetType]("System.Int32")
    dt.Columns.Add(dcol)

    Dim x As Integer
    x = 5
    Dim xrow As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text / 5)
    Dim xrow2 As Integer = TextBox1.Text / 5
    Dim k As Integer
    While k <> dt.Rows.Count
        If xrow2 = xrow Then
            dt.Rows(k)("DT") = xrow
            xrow2 = 0
        End If
        xrow2 += 1
        k += 1
    End While

    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dt)
    dv.RowFilter = "DT=" & xrow
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv


    Dim dt1 As New DataTable

    With dt1

        .Columns.Add("date_time")
        .Columns.Add("R_1")
        .Columns.Add("remark")

    End With



    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("date_time").Value, dr.Cells("R_1").Value, dr.Cells("remark").Value)
    Next

    Dim rptdoc As CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptdoc = New CrystalReport1
    rptdoc.SetDataSource(dt1)

   End sub
```

Comment: So you want to say if the time is between 9:00 - 10:00 (1 hour interval), then it should show all the related times like 9:05, 9:10. Something like this?

Comment: You are almost near but buddy if i miss 9:25 reading then it should not show additional reading on 10:05 for 12 reading

Comment: Will it work if I give a sql query in this regard I mean to check the time interval?